# Create method parse that outputs strings that belong in a List

Tags: java, parsing

I want to create a class `Parser` i.e.

```
public class Parser{
   List<String> lines;
```

that has a method `parse` which takes in a list of lines as an input and outputs all the strings (one string in each line) in the list i.e.

```
public String parse(List<String> lines){
```

For example, if my list has: `List lines = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"one", "two three"})`

my output for `Parser.parse(lines)` will be

```
one
two three
```

May I get some help with the method `parse`?

Comment: *BTW:* That's not parsing, that's formatting.

Comment: `public String parse(List<String> lines) { return String.join(System.lineSeparator(), lines); }`